# What is significance of Shashtanga Namaskaram near Kodimaram/Dwajastambha/flagpole?

Tags: belief, culture

Why do we do Shashtanga Namaskara near Kodimaram/Flag Pole/Dwajastamaba ? I often watched people also doing Namaskaram near Garbha Gruha (inner sanctorum)? Please clarify me which one is the right way and procedure to do Namaskaram.

Comment: Duplicate question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/492/what-is-the-significance-of-sashtang-namaskar

Comment: thanks @Student I had got answer for my question, eventhough I want to know can we do Namaskaram near Garbha Gruha (inner sanctorum) and whether the procedure is same for men and women.

Comment: @Gayathri Sashtanga Namaskaram is only for men. Women should not do Sashtanga Namaskaram. Women have only Panchanga Namaskaram. The Chest portion and portion of stomach and below parts upto knee of ladies are not allowed to touch the ground.

Comment: @Gayathri  Also if you are in Garbha Alayam then it should be done perpendicular to facing of the murti or lingam. If the idol faces east or west , do namaskaram to either south or north and if idol faces south or north, do namaskaram to east or west. For example, if one do namaskaram falling towards the idol, then the feet goes towards the vahana i.e nandi if saiva tempe, or garuda if vaishnava temple. so that is why do in the perpendicular direction. Also make sure that no other minor deities or their temples of Alayam are there to the direction of your feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gayatri--You have to do the namaskaram near the dwajasthamba or kodimaram only. That too before seeing God you have to do this --  at the entry point. Because the Lord is supreme of the entire world and he sees thru dwajasthamba. You should not do namaskaram near sanctum sanctorum as this is garbhagriha which is surrounded by mantra avahanams and on the peeta the Lord stand and gives blessings to the devotees. He is surrounded by the prathispanam of mantras.